# If one thread writes to a location and another thread is reading, can the second thread see the new value then the old?

Tags: multithreading, consistency, cpu-cache

Start with x = 0.  Note there are no memory barriers in any of the code below.

volatile int x = 0

Thread 1:

```
while (x == 0) {}
print "Saw non-zer0"
while (x != 0) {}
print "Saw zero again!"
```

Thread 2:

```
x = 1
```

Is it ever possible to see the second message, "Saw zero again!", on any (real) CPU?  What about on x86_64?

Similarly, in this code:

volatile int x = 0.

Thread 1:

```
while (x == 0) {}
x = 2
```

Thread 2:

```
x = 1
```

Is the final value of x guaranteed to be 2, or could the CPU caches update main memory in some arbitrary order, so that although x = 1 gets into a CPU's cache where thread 1 can see it, then thread 1 gets moved to a different cpu where it writes x = 2 to that cpu's cache, and the x = 2 gets written back to main memory before x = 1.

Comment: Speaking in the context of the C language: since this is a data race and a data race is undefined behavior, then anything could happen.  There's really not much point trying to reason about it.

Comment: Impossible to answer without a programming language (and be it x86 instructions).

Comment: In most languages the compiler can legally rewrite `print(x); print(x);` to `old = x; print(x); print(old);`. So the answer is yes in most languages.

Comment: @MichaelBurr In the context of the C language, there are only `volatile` operations on shared objects, and these have to be **performed exactly, according to the ABI; that is part of the observable behavior**. So we have exactly the semantics provided by the CPU when `int` objects conforming the ABI (aligned accordingly) are read and written. There is no UB, only ABI and CPU specific behavior.

Comment: @usr In C and C++, volatile means: execute these memory operations in asm in the exact order. And don't optimize any such operation even it might appear redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be, "this is exactly the job of the CPU cache coherency."  x86 processors implement the [MESI protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), which guarantee that the second thread can't see the new value then the old.

Comment: Cache coherency by itself does not guarantee any memory ordering model. The MESI protocol doesn't say how reads/writes from two different contexts would be ordered, it only only guarantees that whatever order they will form, the most recent value is always read (even if written by another core or socket).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's entirely possible. The compiler could, for example, have just written `x` to memory but still have the value in a register. One `while` loop could check memory while the other checks the register.

It doesn't happen due to CPU caches because cache coherency hardware logic makes the caches invisible on all CPUs you are likely to actually use.

Theoretically, the write race you talk about could happen due to posted write buffering and read prefetching. Miraculous tricks were used to make this impossible on x86 CPUs to avoid breaking legacy code. But you shouldn't expect future processors to do this.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any references or example code/blog posts that discuss this in detail?  Also, I'll update the question to use volatile variables, to get around the register problem; that's more of what I originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside for a second tricks done by the compiler (even ones allowed by language standards), I believe you're asking how the micro-architecture could behave in such scenario. Keep in mind that the code would most likely expand into a busy wait loop of `cmp [x] + jz` or something similar, which hides a load inside it. This means that [x] is likely to live in the cache of the core running thread 1.

At some point, thread 2 would come and perform the store. If it resides on a different core, the line would first be invalidated completely from the first core. If these are 2 threads running on the same physical core - the store would immediately affect all chronologically younger loads.

Now, the most likely thing to happen on a modern out-of-order machine is that all the loads in the pipeline at this point would be different iterations of the same first loop (since any branch predictor facing so many repetitive "taken" resolution is likely to assume the branch will continue being taken, until proven wrong), so what would happen is that the first load to encounter the new value modified by the other thread will cause the matching branch to simply flush the entire pipe from all younger operations, without the 2nd loop ever having a chance to execute.

However, it's possible that for some reason you did get to the 2nd loop (let's say the predictor issue a not-taken prediction just at the right moment when the loop condition check saw the new value) - in this case, the question boils down to this scenario:

```
  Time -->                                        
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
thread 1

    cmp [x],0                                            execute
    je ...                                                  execute (not taken)
    ...
    cmp [x],0        execute
    jne ...              execute (not taken)
  Can_We_Get_Here:
    ...

thread2 

    store [x],1                          execute
```

In other words, given that most modern CPUs may execute instructions out of order, can a younger load be evaluated before an older one to the same address, allowing the store (from another thread) to change the value so it may be observed inconsistently by the loads.

My guess is that the above timeline is quite possible given the nature of out-of-order execution engines today, as they simply arbitrate and perform whatever operation is ready. However, on most x86 implementations there are safeguards to protect against such a scenario, since the memory ordering rules strictly [say](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html)  -

```
8.2.3.2 Neither Loads Nor Stores Are Reordered with Like Operations
```

Such mechanisms may detect this scenario and flush the machine to prevent the stale/wrong values becoming visible. So The answer is - no, it should not be possible, unless of course the software or the compiler change the nature of the code to prevent the hardware from noticing the relation. Then again, memory ordering rules are sometimes flaky, and i'm not sure all x86 manufacturers adhere to the exact same wording, but this is a pretty fundamental example of consistency, so i'd be very surprised if one of them missed it.